# How to import python-file from another folder and sub-folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-import, init

Now i'm working on Python 3.6.8, Now i'm got stuck about import file. 
It's can't work

```sh
├── db
│   ├── commit.py
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── database.ini
│   └── __init__.py
└── main.py
```

This my code structure. for each file ,

```py
#commit.py 

from config import config 

class Commit():
     #many function
     #some process. Which use package from config
```

```py
#config.py 

class config():
    #some process.
```

```py
#database.ini 
#It's text file
```

```py
#__init__.py 
import commit 
import config
```

```py
#main.py 

from db import commit 
from db import config 

class Main():
    #many function
    #include calling commit function 

if __name__=="__main__":
   #work with main function
```

But my program still error. When i run main.py and This below is error message.

```sh
db/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
import commit
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'commit'
```

Why it can't work? because is Python 3+ ? how to fix this.

Comment: What happens if you completely remove the `import` statements from `__init__.py`?

Comment: it's still same error.

Comment: All right, next try. Then what happens if you change `__init__.py` to have `from . import commit` instead of `import commit`? Or just `import .commit`?

Comment: It's still "ModuleNotFoundError" : No mudle named ....

Comment: Can you do ```import db.commit``` and ```import db.config``` in ```main.py``` ?

Comment: It's still error, in same issue TT

Comment: Can you check ```sys.path``` before importing ```commit```. It should have the absolute path of the parent directory of ```main.py```

Comment: how to check sys.path?

Answer (score 0):

The following structure should works:

```
# main.py
from db.commit import *
from db.config import *

class Main():
   #many function
   #include calling commit function 

if __name__== "__main__":
   #work with main function
```

I suppose that you need to import everything from commit and config file. But if you need just the Commit class or the config class you can modify code like the following:

```
from db.commit import Commit
from db.config import config
```

Then other files

```
# init.py
# no imports
```

Remove imports from init.py

```
# config.py
class config():
    #some process.
```

config.py it's fine like your version

```
# commit.py
from .config import *

class Commit():
    #many function
    #some process. Which use package from config
```

In this way should works correctly.

**edit after comment**

If from main.py, you import functions contained in commit.py module and in commit.py module you import functions contained in main.py module you will have circular imports.

In order to fix it you should organized the project structure in another way. 
For example you can move Main class in another file and then import it in both, main.py and commit.py.

Comment: It's work with main.py . but when run direct with commit.py this can't work. "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.config'; '__main__' is not a package". Then it's effect to main.py. Now my commit.py can't import config.py. Now the main.py It's can run but got error from commit.py cause it's can't import config.py in self.